# PhpStorm is set to 8.1.7 but throws error on 8.0.* methods

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have this code snippet that PhpStorm does not like:

```php
public function __construct(LogFacade $logFacade)
{
    private LogFacade $logFacade
} ()
```

It mainly says `Undefined constant 'LogFacade'` and `Expected: semicolon`.

We are running on docker container which has PHP version 8.1.7:

```bash
martin@463a39853ae1:/web$ php -v
PHP 8.1.7 (cli) (built: Jun 13 2022 13:56:32) (ZTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
martin@463a39853ae1:/web$
```

and so is PhpStorm (language level+interpreter):
[image: PhpStorm version of PHP]

When I change it to older version, it works completely fine (**But the project is using the first snippet all over the place**:

```php
private LogFacade $logFacade;

public function __construct(LogFacade $logFacade)
{
    $this->logFacade = $logFacade;
}
```

Comment: The two snippets are different, I'm not sure what you're trying to illustrate. The 2nd snippet is valid, whereas the 1st is indeed missing a semicolon at the 3rd line and has to declare the private property within the class and not within the constructor.

Comment: Question edited, thanks for the hint

Comment: @Martin Your edit ... your first code example is still invalid. Are you trying to use "Constructor property promotion"? If so -- you are doing it wrong (your code sample). Check here: https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#constructor-property-promotion You do not declare them in the constructor body (like you have done) but in the actual parameters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first snippet should declare the visibility inside the constructor arguments. There is then no need to reference it again in the constructor body

```php
public function __construct(private LogFacade $logFacade) {}
```

Comment: Learnt something new today – constructor promotion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Properties would need to be declared within a class, your class should look something as shown below for it to work:

```php
class MyClass
{
    private LogFacade $logFacade;

    public function __construct(LogFacade $logFacade)
    {
        $this->logFacade = $logFacade;
    }
}
```

More details can be found here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php